# Flink - Failure at recovering from savepoint (checkpoint) . cause by java.lang.IllegalStateException: There is no operator for the state

Tags: apache-flink

**The problem:**

The flink job-manager couldn't recovery from a checkpoint.
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: There is no operator for the state

**Background:**
I'm running a flink 1.6.3 over k8s. and I'm using incremental checkpoint on rocksdb.

I tryied to pass the parameter `--allowNonRestoredState` in order to skip savepoint state that cannot be restored

**From my log:**

> 2019-02-06 08:51:08.068 [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint  -
>   --allowNonRestoredState
>
> 2019-02-06 08:51:22.827 [flink-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-14] INFO 
>   o.a.f.runtime.checkpoint.ZooKeeperCompletedCheckpointStore  -
>   Recovering checkpoints from ZooKeeper. 2019-02-06 08:51:22.883
>   [flink-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-14] INFO 
>   o.a.f.runtime.checkpoint.ZooKeeperCompletedCheckpointStore  - Found 1
>   checkpoints in ZooKeeper. 2019-02-06 08:51:22.883
>   [flink-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-14] INFO 
>   o.a.f.runtime.checkpoint.ZooKeeperCompletedCheckpointStore  - Trying
>   to fetch 1 checkpoints from storage. 2019-02-06 08:51:22.884
>   [flink-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-14] INFO 
>   o.a.f.runtime.checkpoint.ZooKeeperCompletedCheckpointStore  - Trying
>   to retrieve checkpoint 1612. 2019-02-06 08:51:22.977
>   [flink-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-14] INFO 
>   org.apache.flink.runtime.checkpoint.CheckpointCoordinator  - Restoring
>   job 00000000000000000000000000000000 from latest valid checkpoint:
>   Checkpoint 1612 @ 1549376250641 for 00000000000000000000000000000000.
>   2019-02-06 08:51:22.982 [flink-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-14] ERROR
>   org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint  - Fatal error
>   occurred in the cluster entrypoint. java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobExecutionException: Could not set
>   up JobManager
>           at org.apache.flink.util.function.CheckedSupplier.lambda$unchecked$0(CheckedSupplier.java:36)
>           at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1590)
>           at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:39)
>           at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:415)
>           at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
>           at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
>           at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
>           at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
>   Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobExecutionException:
>   Could not set up JobManager
>           at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobManagerRunner.(JobManagerRunner.java:176)
>           at org.apache.flink.runtime.dispatcher.Dispatcher$DefaultJobManagerRunnerFactory.createJobManagerRunner(Dispatcher.java:1058)
>           at org.apache.flink.runtime.dispatcher.Dispatcher.lambda$createJobManagerRunner$5(Dispatcher.java:308)
>           at org.apache.flink.util.function.CheckedSupplier.lambda$unchecked$0(CheckedSupplier.java:34)
>           ... 7 common frames omitted Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: There is no operator for the state
>   b22e6e8baea7d7e562d5a233f3301ce1
>           at org.apache.flink.runtime.checkpoint.StateAssignmentOperation.checkStateMappingCompleteness(StateAssignmentOperation.java:569)
>           at org.apache.flink.runtime.checkpoint.StateAssignmentOperation.assignStates(StateAssignmentOperation.java:77)
>           at org.apache.flink.runtime.checkpoint.CheckpointCoordinator.restoreLatestCheckpointedState(CheckpointCoordinator.java:1049)
>           at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobMaster.createAndRestoreExecutionGraph(JobMaster.java:1138)
>           at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobMaster.(JobMaster.java:294)
>           at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobManagerRunner.(JobManagerRunner.java:157)
>           ... 10 common frames omitted 2019-02-06 08:51:23.013 [TransientBlobCache shutdown hook] INFO 
>   org.apache.flink.runtime.blob.TransientBlobCache  - Shutting down BLOB
>   cache 2019-02-06 08:51:23.033 [BlobServer shutdown hook] INFO 
>   org.apache.flink.runtime.blob.BlobServer  - Stopped BLOB server at
>   0.0.0.0:6124

**Expected result:**

The job will start running from the latest checkpoint and will skip the state that cannot be restored

Comment: Could you share the complete logs with us? The error message indicates that `--allowNonRestoredState` was not properly recognized.